# How to have an always running method in react that can be called from any component?

Tags: reactjs

My problem is that I am trying to create a cryptocurrency trading simulator and I need some dummy data that updates itself automatically so it can be accessed from any other component and keeps track of all previously stored data so I am able to make graphs etc. How would you have an always running method or something relative to that in a class that can return whatever the current value is in React? Where would I start with this? I have tried to schedule it on firebase but that requires a subscription to google cloud. That is why I would rather something local.

Thanks

Comment: There's no magic here, React code is still just on page JavaScript so the short answer is "by importing something that points to exactly the same object in every component".

Comment: I don't quite understand, would you be able to give a code example. I was thinking of using something like a singleton which can be called each time but I don't know how to implement that

Comment: are you building a bundle using webpack or something?

Comment: No, I am not using a webpack, just standard React with Redux and Firebase/Firestore

Comment: okay, but "standard React" means create-react-app and the like, which uses webpack. So... are you building a bundle, or are you doing something different from 99.99% of folks? =)

Comment: Oh no, I am using create react app for sure. Didn't realize that it was a webpack

Comment: In that case: cool, answer written.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is constantly changing, and you want to be able to access all previously stored data, then you will likely want to keep your data in some global state.  If you want various components to be able to access it, then you can use something like [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).  If you want the other components to be able to communicate back to the global state, or communicate with each other, your best bet is [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).  These are global state management systems.  They are not simple to learn, especially if you are a beginner.  But they are well worth taking the time to learn and master, as they are commonly used in most real-world React projects.  Are you already using one of these systems?

Comment: I am already using React Redux, but I would not know how to implement that

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic here: it's still just plain old JavaScript, so just have every component hook into the same object and you're done. If you're bundling up node code using webpack, because you're using `create-react-app` it couldn't be easier (well, okay, it could be, but this is *pretty* easy):

create some file like `use-this-everyone.js`:

```js
const mything = { 
  // literally _anything_ you want synchronised goes here.
  // properties, functions, class bindings, whatever you like.
};

modulde.exports = mything;
```

and then in each component, import that:

```js
const React = require('react');
const mything = requjire('path/to/use-this-everyone.js');

class Blah extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }

  render() {
    // boom, `mything` is the same thing for _everything_ that require'd it
  }
}
```

The reason this works is because Node, and webpack, cache modules. By turning this single object into "a module", ever single thing that `require`s it will get a reference to the *exact same object* and so you can use that as quick and easy synchronization device between all components.

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable enough but would mything continuously change data even when it is not used. Would data in mything be dynamic or static. I need it to run in the background until I need to access it

Comment: What does "not used" mean? Again, _it's just more javascript_ so if you need it to constantly be updating itself against some data source, by all means: make it do that. Stop thinking about this as something special: it's just some JS code that's loaded into memory but that everything has direct access to, provided they required it in. It's exactly the same as `var a = {}; b = { a: a }; c = { a: a };`: both `b` and `c` have access to _the same_ thing. Give that object `a` an `addEventListener` function, and have it run a `fetch(...).then(data => listeners.forEach)` loop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're building a simulator, so depending on your needs, you could just look at the current `DateTime`, and calculate some dummy data when called upon. Example (this is representative, and will not work out of the box):

```
const ledger = [
  { value: Math.random(), time: Date.now() }
];

function getSimulatedData() {
  const lastRecord = ledger[ledger.length - 1];
  const lastUpdated = lastRecord.time;
  const now = Date.now();

  // this could take a loooooong time to do. Don't do exactly this.
  for (let i = lastUpdated; i < now; i += 1000) {
    ledger = [ ...ledger, { value: Math.random(), time: i } ];
  }

  return ledger;
}

export default getSimulatedData;
```

If that won't work for you, you could just have your function update its own state w/ `setTimeout`.

```
const ledger = [];

function updateSimulatedData() {
  ledger = [ ...ledger, { value: Math.random(), time: Date.now() } ];

  setTimeout(updateSimulatedData, 1000);
}

updateSimulatedData();

export default ledger;
```

This approach actually will run in the background every second.